# Ruby MiniTest test design advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing http/https content for images that are on a web application running Rails 2.3. The layout is basic. I have my controllers with accompanying test directories including functional and integration folders with tests.

I'm still relatively new to Rails but I was wondering if there was a way to create a file that can test attachments across different controllers. For example, I need to test if whether the images on this web app are either http or https on the About/Projects/People/Accounts/ and Explore controllers. Instead of opening each of the about_controller_test, project_controller_test, etc. files writing the lines of code, I wanted to know if there was a way that I can make a master file that includes all of the controllers.

What I would like to do is to create some sort of module that I can include/extend the controllers in. This makes sense in my head but I run into the problem with naming conventions. If I wanted to make an attachments_test.rb, I wouldn't be able to do this because I don't have an attachments_controller.rb file that maps to it. How can I work around this?

All I would like is to make a file named along the lines of testing_attachment_protocols_test.rb which doesn't map to any controller but where I can put my tests in. I want to have one file to write my tests for different controllers instead of writing 1 test in several files. Would this file be included into test_helper.rb? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---------EDIT-----------------------

I figured out the structure that I basically would like to implement for the test. Below is the general structure of the test that I would like to do.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
require 'open-uri'

def controller
  ......
end

class controller; def rescue_action(e) raise e end: end

class controller <  Test::Unit::TestCase

def setup
 @controller = controller
 @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
 @response = ActionController::TestResponse.new
end

test "attachments url pattern for home page should include http when not logged in" do
  setup
  get :home
  assert not_logged_in
  #puts @response.body
  assert_select("a img", :url =~ /sw.amazonaws/) do |anchor|
    assert_equal 'http', anchor.protocol
  end
 end
end
```

Now the thing that I have trouble now is what to put in the method call for controller. My goal is to try to be as dynamic as possible. My goal is pretty much to create an attribute accessor method for different Controllers. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you want to do feature test in controllers, this is not right way, instead you should write feature test.

Comment: @AnilMaurya do you mean Unit Tests?